# Click on text inside iframe on external domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

This is my current code. It should load up depop.com in an iframe and click on the "Login" button.

How can I do this? It doesn't seem to work and when running it in the console, it is `undefined`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script id="iframe" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var lgnbtn = $("span:contains('Login')");
                lgnbtn.click();
            });
        </script>
        <iframe src="http://www.depop.com" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're going to run into XSS restrictions trying to do this since the site in the iframe does not belong to your domain.

Comment: if you are not an owner of "depop.com" - you can't